# How to set current tab in viewpager with tablayout

Tags: android-viewpager, android-espresso, android-tablayout

I have a custom viewpager (with swiping disabled for reasons) working with a tablayout. The content changes based on which tab is selected. I want to test this using espresso:
1) Click on a particular tab
2) Check some data in a particular page of the tab
How can I do that. I am a novice to espresso

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this, an easy one is to select the element by the tab title, I use this code:

```
Matcher<View> matcher = allOf(withText("TAB TITLE"),
            isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.customTab)));
onView(matcher).perform(click());
SystemClock.sleep(800); // Wait a little until the content is loaded
```

You only have to adapt the matcher to your layout.
Then, check the content.

For example:

```
onView(withId(R.id.someId)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
```

or:

```
onView(withText(R.string.someText)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
```

You can find examples here  in the **Specifying a View Matcher** section: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html

If you are using a RecyclerView to show the content of the tabs have a look at this:
[Espresso RecyclerView inside ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945219/espresso-recyclerview-inside-viewpager/37157492)

Comment: What if the tab has only an icon and no text, how to capture it? withIcon() does not exist in Espresso. Any other alternative?

Comment: In that case you can still use the `withId`, `withTagValue` or create a custom matcher instead of the `withText` one

Comment: From my actual code I passed in a setTag() within my tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setTag(...) but withTagValue() takes a Matcher<Object> as parameter and not a string. Regarding withId(), tabLayout.getTabAt(i) does not have any method for setId(). I can only set the id of the whole layout and not the individual single tab.

Comment: You can use `withTagValue` this way: `onView(withTagValue(is((Object) tagValueString)))` using the `Matcher.is` method to find views with that tag

Comment: I implemented your suggestions but my test is failing. I opened the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028955/check-fragment-visibility-in-viewpager-from-fragmentpageradapter-using-android-e

Answer (score -3):

Espresso should be used when you clearly know what is expected in the UI and so you can verify the same.

In your case, to go to any tab, you can use view action to tap on that tab.
To verify the data, first you should know what data is expected to be there on that tab and then just use matchers to check if they are displayed or not.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to select a specific tab in a ViewPager.