# Espresso RecyclerView inside ViewPager

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso

I am new to Android Espresso library. Trying to test click on `RecyclerView` item inside the `ViewPager`. I've searched the Internet but found nothing about ViewPager. So my question is: how to access `RecyclerView` inside a `ViewPager` using Espresso to perform click?

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you want to tap on *buttonClick*, which is the id of a button inside your RecyclerView.

I use this code:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.buttonToClick), isCompletelyDisplayed()))
            .perform(click());
```

This gets the view with this id which is currently displayed and performs a click on it.

Hope this helps.

P.S.: Also, on *espresso-contrib* there are `RecyclerViewActions` that maybe you can use: `actionOnHolderItem`, `actionOnItem` and `actionOnItemAtPosition`. You can do something like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```