# espresso onData matches multiple views in the hierarchy

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an Activity with 2 ListView, I want to find first ListView's Child but I find first ListView's Child and second ListView, why? please help me.

code:

```
DataInteraction dataInteraction =
            onData(allOf(
                    withClassName(endsWith("LinearLayout")),
                    hasSibling(withText("9.0")),
                    hasSibling(withText("衬衫"))
            ));
        dataInteraction.onChildView(withId(R.id.order_untake_jijia_listview_jia))
                .atPosition(0);
        dataInteraction.perform(ViewActions.click());
```

It find:

```
ListView{id=2131493579, res-name=order_jijia_listview, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768,
            height=659, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, 
            is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, 
            is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, 
            has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=345.0, child-count=7} ****MATCHES****

ListView{id=2131493586, res-name=order_jijia_pop_listview, visibility=VISIBLE, 
            width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, 
            has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, 
            is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, 
            root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0,
            child-count=0} ****MATCHES****
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two matches because you must be using a RecyclerView. That's why espresso finds two elements with the same id defined in the layout.

Have a look at this answer:
[Espresso RecyclerView inside ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945219/espresso-recyclerview-inside-viewpager/37157492#37157492)

Also, I think it can match multiple views would be if there is a leak in your app, but I think it's more probable that you use recyclerview and you only need to access it in a proper way.

There is also the possibility that you have defined the same id in different layouts and some of them are in memory even though they are not on the screen at the same time, in this case you can use the isCompletelyDisplayed() method to match the one which is shown.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to point in which adapter view espresso should do the search/action:

```
onData(allOf(withClassName(endsWith("LinearLayout")),
        hasSibling(withText("9.0")),
        hasSibling(withText("衬衫"))))
             .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.order_jijia_listview))
             .onChildView(withId(R.id.order_untake_jijia_listview_jia))
             .atPosition(0)
             .perform(click());
```